# How to concatenate two strings to build a complete path

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script. In this script I want user to enter a path of a directory. Then I want to append some strings at the end of this string and build a path to some subdirectories.
For example assume user enters an string like this:

```
/home/user1/MyFolder
```

Now I want to create 2 subdirectories in this directory and copy some files there.

```
/home/user1/MyFolder/subFold1
/home/user1/MyFolder/subFold2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is part of your question about getting input from the user, and the other part about building the path? Or just the path?

Answer (score 199):

The POSIX standard mandates that multiple `/` are treated as a single `/` in a file name. Thus
`//dir///subdir////file` is the same as `/dir/subdir/file`.

As such concatenating a two strings to build a complete path is a simple as:

```
full_path="$part1/$part2"
```

Comment: Except if $part1 can be empty string.

Comment: @TuureLaurinolli I don't understand where you're coming from. The above concatenation would still result in a valid path. The path might not exist, but it would still be valid. eg. `"" + "/" + "Documents"` gives `"/Documents"`.

Comment: If the parts themselves are relative paths, and part1 may be empty, then the result might turn from relative to absolute path.

Comment: @TuureLaurinolli Then you could simply add `./` to the front. But maybe the user _wants_ to concat absolute paths. Otherwise they could simply add `./` to the front to force the path to be relative. Also note that `"$path1/./$path2"` is the same as `"$path1/$path2"`.

Comment: @yyny : You can't "simply" add `./`, because if the first path is absolute, then that fails.

Comment: @einpoklum "If the parts themselves are relative paths" kind of precludes the paths from being absolute... I do think a slightly better solution would be `"${path1:-.}/$path2"`, which makes an empty string relative, but allows non-empty paths to be absolute.

Comment: [A path shall not be empty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160554), so the "empty string" case is moot.

Answer (score 45):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a directory: " BASEPATH

SUBFOLD1=${BASEPATH%%/}/subFold1
SUBFOLD2=${BASEPATH%%/}/subFold2

echo "I will create $SUBFOLD1 and $SUBFOLD2"

# mkdir -p $SUBFOLD1
# mkdir -p $SUBFOLD2
```

And if you want to use readline so you get completion and all that, add a `-e` to the call to `read`:

```
read -e -p "Enter a directory: " BASEPATH
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when BASEPATH is empty. What I need is something like that that only adds a / when it doesn't already end of a slash AND isn't empty. Thus, when it ends on a legal filename character.

Comment: BASEPATH is empty is a special case, so don't expect a one liner.  However this should work for your case:
    [ -z $BASEPATH ] && BASEPATH='.';            
    fullpath=${BASEPATH%%/}/subfolder1;      

    echo $fullpath;
RESULT:  ./subfolder1

Answer (score 21):

Won't simply concatenating the part of your path accomplish what you want?

```
$ base="/home/user1/MyFolder/"
$ subdir="subFold1"
$ new_path=$base$subdir
$ echo $new_path
/home/user1/MyFolder/subFold1
```

You can then create the folders/directories as needed.

One convention is to end directory paths with `/` (e.g. `/home/`) because  paths starting with a / could be confused with the root directory.  If a double slash (`//`) is used in a path, it is also still correct.  But, if no slash is used on either variable, it would be incorrect (e.g. `/home/user1/MyFoldersubFold1`).

Comment: why I get this message: Myscript.sh: line 4: /home/user1/MyFolder/subFold1: Is a directory

Comment: You are missing a / from the path. The goal is 
inline `/home/user1/MyFolder/subFold1`

so you would need
inline `new_path=$base/$subdir`. But then what do you do if the path given includes a trailing '/'?

Comment: @Thrasi just add the trailing '/' either to the subdir variable or `newpath=$base/$subdir/` You can play with this directly on the command line

Comment: @user12345, Yes ... still leaves the solution above incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

The following script catenates several (relative/absolute) paths (BASEPATH) with a relative path (SUBDIR):

```
shopt -s extglob
SUBDIR="subdir"
for BASEPATH in '' / base base/ base// /base /base/ /base//; do
  echo "BASEPATH = \"$BASEPATH\" --> ${BASEPATH%%+(/)}${BASEPATH:+/}$SUBDIR"
done
```

The output of which is:

```
BASEPATH = "" --> subdir
BASEPATH = "/" --> /subdir
BASEPATH = "base" --> base/subdir
BASEPATH = "base/" --> base/subdir
BASEPATH = "base//" --> base/subdir
BASEPATH = "/base" --> /base/subdir
BASEPATH = "/base/" --> /base/subdir
BASEPATH = "/base//" --> /base/subdir
```

The `shopt -s extglob` is only necessary to allow BASEPATH to end on multiple slashes (which is probably nonsense). Without extended globing you can just use:

```
echo ${BASEPATH%%/}${BASEPATH:+/}$SUBDIR
```

which would result in the less neat but still working:

```
BASEPATH = "" --> subdir
BASEPATH = "/" --> /subdir
BASEPATH = "base" --> base/subdir
BASEPATH = "base/" --> base/subdir
BASEPATH = "base//" --> base//subdir
BASEPATH = "/base" --> /base/subdir
BASEPATH = "/base/" --> /base/subdir
BASEPATH = "/base//" --> /base//subdir
```

Answer (score 4):

I was working around with my shell script which need to do some path joining stuff like you do.

The thing is, both path like

```
/data/foo/bar

/data/foo/bar/
```

are valid.

If I want to append a file to this path like

```
/data/foo/bar/myfile
```

there was no native method (like os.path.join() in python) in shell to handle such situation.

But I did found a trick

For example , the base path was store in a shell variable

```
BASE=~/mydir
```

and the last file name you wanna join was

```
FILE=myfile
```

Then you can assign your new path like this

```
NEW_PATH=$(realpath ${BASE})/FILE
```

and then you`ll get

```
$ echo $NEW_PATH

/path/to/your/home/mydir/myfile
```

the reason is quiet simple, the "realpath" command would always trim the terminating slash for you if necessary

Answer (score 2):

This should works for empty dir (You may need to check if the second string starts with `/` which should be treat as an absolute path?):

```
#!/bin/bash

join_path() {
    echo "${1:+$1/}$2" | sed 's#//#/#g'
}

join_path "" a.bin
join_path "/data" a.bin
join_path "/data/" a.bin
```

Output:

```
a.bin
/data/a.bin
/data/a.bin
```

Reference: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: What if there are three or more slashes? You can use a recursive `sed` call, ala `sed -e ':loop' -e 's#//#/#' -e 't loop'`. (Form is compatible with non-POSIX implementations.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up concating all arguments *(`$*`)* with '/' *(`IFS=/` - **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator)* as separator and then removing all repeating '/' (`tr -s /`).

My function looks like this:

```sh
join_paths() {
    (IFS=/; echo "'$*'" | tr -s /)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dunes' basic solution, but accounting for empty strings:

```
[ -z "$rootpath" ] && rootpath="."
fullpath="${rootpath}/${subdir}"
```